# PHP 8.0 extension settings for compliance with wordpress 5.7

Tags: php, wordpress, compatibility, php-extension, php-8

I tried updating to PHP 8.0 in my cPanel and my WordPress site went down. I reverted to 7.4 but just wondering what extensions I should tick in order to ensure full compatibility with WordPress 5.7. I think I need the nd_mysqli extension but I'm confused since I see other extensions referencing mysql too.

I also see that the imagick extension is gone from 8.0 too (which I have active in 7.4).

Would welcome any insights. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

**FOLLOW-UP EDIT**

I worked with my hosting provider to get the settings sorted out and it is now working fine with my WordPress site. I'm posting this follow up image so that anyone else having issues with PHP 8.0 and WordPress will benefit.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to look into the error.log. I've experienced deprecated functions are mostly used in old templates and plugins.

Comment: Thanks Markus, that's a good tip.  I'll try that out and have a look again if the site breaks. Most appreciated.

Comment: Hi! The convention here is that Answers and Questions are strictly separate, but it's OK to answer your own question. So rather than editing the solution into the question above, you can post it in the answer box below.